# Error: Cannot install on Intel processor in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1, apple-silicon

When trying `brew install` commands, I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot install on Intel processor in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!

I looked around StackOverflow but most questions/answers talk about Apple M1 chip computers having this issue. My problem however is on an Intel Macbook Pro.

I think the reason for this issue is the following... I reset my MBP and using the Apple migration assistant I copied the files, folders, settings ... of my Apple Mac Mini (with M1 chip).

Comment: This is for every package you want to install ?

Comment: Yes (doctl, stripe-cli, ...)

Comment: You copied the `/opt/homebrew` folder from `m1 mac` to `intel mac`. So when you are running the brew install command, it will try to install it in /opt/homebrew path which is specific to m1. You have to remove `brew` from the `/opt/homebrew` location and install it in `/usr/local/homebrew/` (which is default for intel-based macs). Then you can install any tools.

Comment: Thanks @SaravanakrishnanPk, removing that folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You copied the /opt/homebrew folder from m1 mac to intel mac. So when you are running the brew install command, it will try to install it in /opt/homebrew path which is specific to m1.

You have to remove brew from the /opt/homebrew location and install it in /usr/local/homebrew/ (which is default for intel-based macs). Then you can install any tools.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `/opt/homebrew` folder manually works for me.